# SQL Update all rows for one column with a list of values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

How can I set all rows of a column by manually typing the values?

My table has 3 rows, I want the column named `mycolumn` to have 3 values a, b and c (currently those values are `NULL`):

```
update mytable set mycolumn = ('a','b','c')
ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis
```

EDIT: my table is very simple, I have one column `ID INT NOT NULL` with values 1, 2, 3 and another column `mycolumn` with all NULL values and I want those values to become `'a' where ID = 1`, `'b' where ID=2` etc.

EDIT2: I might have a huge amount of rows, so I want to avoid typing every single ID value where to replace `mycolumn`. Isn't it possible to match the ID values of 1 to 3 to the values 'a', 'b', 'c' in an automatic way, something like `match(ID, ('a','b','c'))` perhaps

***I just want to replace all values of `mycolumn` by increasing order of `ID`. `ID` being strictly equivalent to what I call a row number in a matrix***

EDIT3: I'd like a solution which would work in a general case with all sorts of values, not only the letters of the alphabet given here for simplicity. What if for example my values to replace in `mycolumn` are `('oefaihfoiashfe', 'fiaohoawdihoiwahopah', 'aefohdfaohdao')`? However the `ID` row numbers will always be a sequence from 1 to N by 1.

Comment: This query makes no sense. Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify what you really ask for.

Comment: Umm you can't do like that unless the value is `'a,b,c'`

Comment: see edits. pretty simple

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, you should do this in a single `update`. Like this:

```
update mytable
set    mycolumn = case id when 1 then 'a' when 2 then 'b' when 3 then 'c' end
;
```

More compact (but also more cryptic, and only works in Oracle, while `case` expressions are in the SQL standard):

```
update mytable
set    mycolumn = decode(id, 1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c')
;
```

Note - this only works if there really are only three rows. If you have many more rows, make sure to add `where id in (1, 2, 3)` at the end. Otherwise all the OTHER values (in the other rows) will be updated to `null`!

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it possible to avoid specifying for which ID to replace every time? Again, I might have a huge amount of rows, so this would be impossible to type. Isn't it possible to `match` the `ID` values of 1 to 3 to the values `'a', 'b', 'c'` in an automatic way?

Comment: What if I want to update all millions of unique values instead of just 'a', 'b', 'c'? see edits

Comment: @CatalystRPA - In what way? For example: you may have a lookup table, where this association is given. (1 'a' in one row, 2 'b' in another, etc.) If that is your situation, then **say so**. Again, we can't guess. What are all the possible values (besides 'a', 'b', 'c')? In what order should they be used for the given ID's?

Comment: see new edits, this should be pretty clear. honestly dont know what more to say if you don't understand past this point. I want to replace the values of a column, without having to type a `where` clause or similar for every row - which strictly correspond to the values of `ID`

Comment: @CatalystRPA - You didn't answer my question. Where do the values come from? ('a', 'b', c', and the other thousands of values). And how do you know their order? How do you expect to get an answer to your question, without knowing this detail?

Comment: the values for `mycolumn` 'a', 'b', 'c' until 'z' I typed manually in the sql editor, but now I don't want to do it again for the values of `ID` 1, 2, 3 , 26 therefore I am looking for a better way.

Comment: @CatalystRPA - That's only 26 values. That is not a "huge amount of rows". Still, where do the values come from? Are they made-up values, and the only conditions are that they must be strings, all distinct, and all of length at least 1 character? If so, why not just 'abc' || ID? Why do you need 'a', 'b', 'c', ... 'z', and then who-knows-what after that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try an update like the one below. This will update 1 > **a**, 2 > **b**, 3 > **c**, 4 > **d**, etc. When you reach ID 27, since there are no more letters, it will begin at **a** again and continue down the alphabet.

```sql
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycolumn = CASE MOD (id, 26)
                       WHEN 0 THEN 'z'
                       ELSE CHR (MOD (id, 26) + 96)
                  END;
```

#### Update

To update based on any list of values, you can try an update statement like the one below. If you add a 4th item to the comma delimited list, ID 4 in **mytable** will be set to whatever you specified as the 4th value.

```sql
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycolumn =
           (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
              FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS row_num, t.COLUMN_VALUE
                      FROM TABLE (
                               sys.odcivarchar2list ('oefaihfoiashfe',
                                                     'fiaohoawdihoiwahopah',
                                                     'aefohdfaohdao')) t)
             WHERE row_num = id);
```

Comment: Instead of `CHR (MOD (id, 26) + 96)` can I use `('a','b','c')`, etc as in my original question?

Comment: no, you can't use `('a','b','c')` as that is not valid Oracle syntax for updating a column.

Comment: so what if instead of a, b, c my values are `('oefaihfoiashfe', 'fiaohoawdihoiwahopah', 'aefohdfaohdao')` ? see edits

Comment: Just added an update that should allow you to update the IDs to those values.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . A row can only have one value.  Perhaps something like this to assign random values:

```
update mytable
    set mycolumn = (case floor(dbms_random.random * 3)
                        case 0 then 'a' case 1 then 'b' else 'c'
                    end)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I'd just like the first row to have 'a'  in the column `mycolumn`, second row 'b' and third 'c'

Comment: @CatalystRPA . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first" row.

Comment: @CatalystRPA - you need to explain what you mean by "first", "second" and "third". Gordon is partially right - rows in SQL tables are unordered, UNLESS you specify an order. So - what does "first" row mean, in your real-life problem?

Answer (score -1):

if you want the 3 rows to have different values a, b and c then you will have to write 3 update statements.

```
update mytable set mycolumn = 'a' where id = 1;
update mytable set mycolumn = 'b' where id = 2;
update mytable set mycolumn = 'c' where id = 3;
```

Comment: So I have to do `update set mycolumn = 'a' where ID =1` three times? what if I have 54687434643163465464 rows of data? is there really not a simpler way?

Comment: @CatalystRPA - What **ID**? This is the first time you said anything about an ID column. Do you understand why people can't help you yet? You are not explaining the full problem. We can't read your mind.

Comment: I don't see how your three `update` statements will result in the three rows having three different values in the colum. Rather, after the first update all the values will be 'a'; after the second, all will be 'b' (negating the first update entirely), and the same after the third update. Overall, after all three updates, ALL values in the column will be 'c'. Not a good answer, sorry.